Running NPM @stoplight/prism CLI in Powershell script
I am using Prism mock server from Stoplight, to start a simple OpenAPI mock server locally. I want to run this within a Powershell script that should be able to start a prism host on a specific OpenAPI file, run some tests on this OpenAPI mock, then shutdown the mock server, rinse and repeat these step for alle API's that should be tested.
The problem is that when my script is executing
npx prism mock <openapi-file>

Then the script is stuck within that PS session waiting for me to cancel the process running prism.
How can I invoke a prism instance within my PS Script? I need to be able to start and stop that session within my script.

If you don't need to monitor any output, you can do $process = Start-Process -PassThru -WindowStyle Hidden npx 'prism mock <openapi-file>' to run the command in an invisible child process; then use $process.Kill($true) later to kill the process.

Otherwise, consider using a background job

@mklement0 As the command it is running is an 'npx ...' it seems like the process window will shutdown after a short period of time, while I can see the TCP port used is still assigned to a node.js process. Any way to come around this?

You can try $process = Start-Process -PassThru cmd '/k npx prism mock <openapi-file>' to run the command in a stay-open cmd.exe session, so you can see what's happening.
